# Retrieve a value stored within an XML using PHP

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I want to navigate to a particular url and don't want to hard code the value each time. Is there a way to call 'SELENIUM_BASEURL' instead to do this.

$this->url('http://www.google.com');

phpunit.xml...

```
<php>
    <!-- define some constants to use in our test classes -->
    <const name="SELENIUM_HOST" value="127.0.0.1"/>
    <const name="SELENIUM_BASEURL" value="http://www.google.com"/>
</php>

<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="SeleniumSetup">
        <directory>tests/integration/</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use `SimpleXML` in this case:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('phpunit.xml');
$element = $xml->xpath('//php/const[@name="SELENIUM_BASEURL"]');
$selenium_baseurl = $element[0]->attributes()->value;
echo $selenium_baseurl; // http://www.google.com
```

Or using `DOMDocument`:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('phpunit.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$selenium_baseurl = $xpath->evaluate('string(//php/const[@name="SELENIUM_BASEURL"]/@value)');
echo $selenium_baseurl; // http://www.google.com
```

Then:

```
$this->url($seleniium_baseurl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined constants in your XML, so you can access them the usual way:

```
$this->url(SELENIUM_BASEURL);
```